# Wrapping text to fill available height before expanding in width

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` element with two `span` elements inside - one with large font size and another with no adjustments.

I want to achieve an effect where:

- the first span element defines the height of the parent `div`
- the second `span` element wraps to use up all the height made available by the first `span` while maintaining minimum width (but still grow in width when available height is used up)

What I have:

[image: Initial example]

What I want to achieve:

[image: Example of desired effect]

I have tried using different variations of `min-width`/`width:min-content` and `flex-basis` with no success.

Thanks!

[Codepen used in the examples.](https://codepen.io/BaconBad/pen/abjGGbe)

Comment: Adding the css .break-text{width: 88px;} should help

Comment: It would for this case, but not necessarily with dynamically sized and sourced content.

Comment: Can you not add a fixed width for the number? .large-text{width:20%} and a little padding-left for the .break-text in case the number might be a 3 or 4-digit and couldn't fit in the 20%

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't address my main concern. I am looking for a more general solution to wrapping text in a way that it takes up the least width while not overflowing or expanding the parent div vertically.